# Jsonpath array length validation issue

Tags: apache-camel, jsonpath

I am parsing an json and verify array length like below

```
from("direct:parseJson")
        .setHeader("numberOfBooks").jsonpath("$..books.length()", int.class)
        .choice()
                .when( simple("${header.numberOfBooks} == '1'"))
                         .log("One book")
                 .otherwise()
                         .log("multiple");
```

Above Code works, but i am looking for option if we can avoid line 2 with
below

```
 .when( simple("${jsonpath(' $..books.length() ', int.class)} == 1") )
```

its throwing error

```
Caused by:
org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException:
Unknown function: jsonpath(' $..books.length() ', int.class) == 1 at
location 0
${jsonpath(' $..books.length() ', int.class)} == 1
```

second try
i set header with constant to verify simple expression works or not

```
.when().jsonpath("$..books.length() > ${header.numberOfBooks}")

Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Could not parse token starting at position 18
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PathCompiler.fail(PathCompiler.java:616) ~[json-path-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PathCompiler.readNextToken(PathCompiler.java:152) ~[json-path-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonPath directly in your when clause, as described at the [camel documentation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jsonpath/src/main/docs/jsonpath-language.adoc). Your code would look like this:

```
from("direct:parseJson")
        .choice()
        .when().jsonpath("$..books.length() == '1'")
                 .log("One book")
             .otherwise()
                 .log("multiple");
```

Comment: Its now allowed, I am getting error "The method jsonpath(String) is undefined for the type ChoiceDefinition"

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan which camel version are you running?

Comment: I am using 2.24.1, i go through document and couldn't find where they mentioned we can use jsonpath in choice, All examples contain when()

Comment: Oh, for Sure. I missed the `when()` in my example. I'll update it

Comment: but with 'when' its not working
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExpressionIllegalSyntaxException: Illegal syntax: $..books.length() == '1'
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Could not parse token starting at position 18